# Lifecycle or any event to know when a defferable view have been loaded

Tags: angular

It doesn't seems to exist any lifecycle based on defferable views.
I wonder if there is an alternative (like a way to emit an event when the element is fully built).

I don't even know in which real case you might need it (but I have the feeling that I will need it one day ^^') so I will use a dum example :

-1 You have an element in your template that is in a @defer block.

-2 You use a @ViewChild to get that element in your typescript.

-3 You use Renderer2 to do something with it.

How can I know when I can execute the step 3 ? (that will fail if @ViewChild can't find the target)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a setter on the `ViewChild` and (if needed) make a `Subject` emit a value having checked that the child is ready.

```
onViewLoaded = new Subject<void>();
@ViewChild('myElem') set viewLoaded(content: ElementRef | undefined) {
    if (content == undefined) return;
    this.onViewLoaded.next()
}
```

[Here a simple StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-l4nkdr?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)